# TypeError: require(...) is not a function (Node.js) [server.js]

Tags: node.js, npm

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));

app.use('/', require('../routes')(express));

exports.server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server active on', port);
});
```

Am I missing a npm package?

> **Error**
>
> ```
> TypeError: require(...) is not a function
> at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\url-shortener\src\server.js:12:34
>   at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
>   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
>   at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>   at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
>   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
>   at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
> ```

Comment: What is in your `../routes`?

Comment: I misspelled exports as export in ```module.exports = function (string) {
  console.log(string);
}```

Answer (score 0):

Your `../routes` source file is not exporting a function.

Try replacing this line:

```
app.use('/', require('../routes')(express));
```

with:

```
console.log( require('../routes') );
```

I bet it prints an object (`{ ... }`) rather than a function.

---

Inside your `../routes` file you need to explicitly export the important function:

```
module.exports = importantFunction;

function importantFunction(string) {
  console.log(string);
}
```

Now you scripts which import it can call it.

```
require('../routes')("hi") // should log "hi"
```